# Is it possible to deploy Python AWS Lambda on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Python AWS Lambda running on a Linux, but due to some dependencies, I need it to be deployed on a Windows. I have tried using Python Azure Functions and have successfully deployed it on a Linux as well, but found out they cannot be deployed on Windows. Is it possible to do it with AWS Lambda?
Basically my solution has a few .exe that need to be run by a python library (Tesseract OCR and pytesseract)

Comment: When you use Lambda, you don't manage or even see the server that is underneath. AWS automatically manages the containers and infrastructure, while you only need to worry with your code. Could you explain what do you mean when you say you are running Lambda on a VM?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, it doens't have to be a VM, but if it's running on cloud through a service plan I need it to be running on Windows. Basically my solution has a few .exe that need to be run by a python library (Tesseract OCR and pytesseract)

Comment: To run on Windows (or Linux, for that matter), you won't be able to use neither AWS Lambda nor Azure Functions. You will need to create a regular Python script, such as example.py, and install the proper dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda and Azure Functions are considered Function as a Service (FaaS) solutions, where the developer worries about the code and the cloud provider worries about availability, scalability and the platform underneath to run the code.

In that aspect, you can't run any of them on a server. If you need specific Windows dependencies, you must create a Python project as you normally would, install the dependencies and configure the Windows Server, being responsible for infrastructure and OS configurations and management.